# What is the most pythonic way for keeping a running total of occurrences from a generator?

Tags: python

If you have a generator or set of inputs that are not unique and that I can't just query or store in memory how can I best keep a running tally?

If memory is not an issue, creating a list than using count or using Counter as in this [Question/Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item)

However, without sufficient memory or no knowledge of the items, I think a dict makes most sense. Key being the values coming in and value being the count. Is there a better way though?

An example would be possibly be a non-equally weighted random generation of numbers. like an infinite sided die where there are a lot more of some numbers than other but we don't know which numbers those are.

Comment: A `Counter` is exactly what you are describing

Answer (score 1):

A `collections.Counter` can work on an iterable which can give an iterator only returning (and holding in memory) the next item needed.

Example

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import islice

import random


def producer():
    while True:
        yield int(random.normalvariate(300, 100))


data = Counter(islice(producer(), 400))

print(data)
```

The `400` can be replaced by a much larger value and it is only the memory needed to store each appearing value once with the count of appearance (like the dict you described).